# Calculate absolute/relative difference between two means and confidence interval by group in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am trying to calculate the absolute difference and relative difference between two means with their 95%confidence intervals for different countries. I would like the create additional columns for absolute difference, relative difference and their respective CIs.

I tried this with some made-up data:

```
library(data.table)

country <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
year <- c(2011, 2018, 2005, 2015)
mean <- c(18.2, 7.5, 11.5, 5.2)
lower <- c(16.3, 6.4, 9.4, 4.4)
upper <- c(20.2, 8.8, 14.1, 6.3)
N <- c(4000, 5000, 6000, 7000)
data <- data.table(country, year, mean, lower, upper, N)
```

For this, the data should be grouped by country, then calculate the differences in means between the first and last year with their CIs. I tried something like this:

```
data <- data %>%
group_by(country) %>%
slice(c(which.min(year), which.max(year))) %>%
arrange(year, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
mutate(absolute_diff = last(mean) - mean,
       rel_diff = absolute_diff / first(mean)*100)
```

But could not calculate the CIs.

The output should look as follows (this is made up data):

```
country absolute_diff rel_diff CI_abs         CI_rel
1 A      -10.7        -58.8    -12.1-(-9.1)   -62.1-(-56.2)
2 B      -6.3         -54.8    -8.1-(-5.1)    -56.3-(-52.8)
```

I tried to use `prop.test()`to replicate this function f() from [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), but only got errors. I also tried to write my own function but did not succeed since I am not familiar with writing functions, especially for grouped data.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: have you any standard deviation on your data?

Comment: Could you please let me know the formula for the rel_diff, CI_abs, CI_rel derivation so we can use them to derive these variables

Comment: Confidence intervals (CI) are typically derived from variance-based statistics, as RicVillalba suggested. If you don't have it, then it is not possible to back-calculate it given the data we see here.

Comment: Thanks @RicVillalba, jkatam and r2evans for your comments. I edited my question so that it contains the lower and upper bounds of the means. I understand that these can be used to calculate the standard deviation,? I also added the formula I used to obtain absolute_diff and rel_diff, but cannot provide the ones for CI_abs or CI_rel as this is where I failed

Comment: There are several ways of calculating "lower and upper bounds" for the means. Maybe what you've provided uses a normal approximation for a 95% confidence interval, `mean +/- 1.96 * sd / sqrt(n)`. But maybe it's something else--different confidence level, different distribution assumption, etc. You can certainly use that formula to "solve" for the standard deviation, but we can't know if that's the right one to use.